# C++ Creating objects from an array of names

Tags: c++, arrays, class, object

This is my first question here and I'm very excited!

I want to create a lot of objects from the class Person getting the name of each one from a string array.

something like this:

```
class Person 
{
// bla bla bla
};

string listOfPersons [5000];

// here i will fill in the whole array with names

for (int i=0;i<5000);i++){
// here: create the objects with the name from the array
// like Person Mary.... Person John... Person... Patricia...

}
```

thanks very much!!

Comment: And your question is now?

Comment: I don't understand the question.

Comment: Hi Pablo, welcome to StackOverflow. Please be more descriptive when you say "it doesn't work". Give an exact error message if possible, as well as expected input and output. Also, you may want to start smaller, maybe 1 person instead of 5k :-)

Comment: ***Person listOfPersons [i]  //here is where it doesnt work*** Correct that will fail for multiple reasons. 1. Your Person array must be declared outside the loop. 2. Don't name it the same as your string array.

Comment: What do you mean with `create object`? If you mean that creating new types at runtime then you cannot.

Comment: thank you everybody. What i means by doesn work is that doesnt create the object. Saying :  error: conflicting declaration...

Comment: Instead of `for (int i=0;i<=5000-1);i++){` just use `for (int i=0;i<5000;i++){`

Comment: there is a ) extra, Im trying to learn how to edit the question again.

Comment: ***Saying : error: conflicting declaration*** Inside your loop you try to declare a new listOfPersons array.

Comment: Even without the extra ) in c++ we typically use `for (int i=0;i<5000;i++){`

Comment: ok drescherjm, thank you. still i dont know how to create this objects from a list. :(

Comment: sorry i put "from text file list". could be from array, text file list, etc. etc.

Comment: When you create an array, the objects are created with it. As of `string listOfPersons [5000];`, you have 5000 `strings`.They are all default constructed (consult a text is you don't know what that means), so for a `string` that means they are all empty. All you need to do is assign values to them.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your updated question, you want to create a source file where these variables names, within the source code, are based on the names in your array.

In this case you will need a write a separate program to generate the source code this way.

Here's a simple mock-up of how to do this

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    fstream fstr("pablos.cpp",ios::out);
    string names[]={string("John"),string("Joe"),string("Sally")};

    if(fstr.is_open()){
        fstr <<     "#include <iostream>\n"  /* include what you need for the code */
                    "#include <Person.h>\n"
                    "int main(){\n";

        for(int i=0;i<3;i++){
            fstr << "   Person " << names[i]<<";\n";
        }

        fstr <<     "   return 0;\n"
                    "}\n";
        fstr.close();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

If you run this program, you will generate a new source file *Pablo.cpp* which looks like this:

```
#include <iostream.h>
#include <Person.h>
int main(){
   Person John;
   Person Joe;
   Person Sally;
   return 0;
}
```

You can now further edit this source code directly, or alter the generating program above, as you see fit before compiling it (if that happens to be the goal).  I'll leave it to you to update this source as you want.  I don't know why you would want to have 5,000 differently named variables in your source code, but it is possible to do in this fashion.

At first glance and based on the comments, it seems like you are suggesting a self modifying source code, which is not the way things work. The source code needs to be compiled in order to *act*, to be executed directly or indirectly.

**Original post** (for reference)

I think you may be getting your constructors mixed up with your arrays, or your string class mixed up with your person class.

The following code will create two separate arrays of 5000 entries each.  If you have, or are able to add, a `setName` method to your Person's class then you can allocate all 5000 Person objects and your 5000 strings.  After that, fill in your string array with the names (it appears you have way to do this already).  Lastly, it is simply a matter of iterating through you Person's array and calling the `setName` method for each entry with the corresponding string.

```
class Person 
{
   // bla bla bla
   // includes a setName(string) method
   //
};

string arrayOfNames [5000];
Person arrayOfPersons [5000];

// after filling the whole array with names...
// (I assume this means arrayOfNames is filled in now..)  

for (int i=0;i<5000;i++){
    arrayOfPersons[i].setName(arrayOfNames[i]);  
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot! Thats work. Is a solution BUT, i would like to set the names of the objects taking those names from the arrayOfNames[]. So, after the loop, having created many objects called John, Mary, Isabella... and not arrayOfPersons [0] = {John}... arrayOfPersons [1] = {Mary}....

Comment: i had the question edited. Thanks for everybody for the patience.

Comment: Ah, I see what you are saying from your edit now.  You want the variable names, within your C++ code to be called this.  Well, the way you would do that, from what I can think, would be to write another program that then writes a .cpp file for you with the names injected into it.

Comment: This kind of thing pops up more often with PHP, JavaScript, CSS, etc (at least in my experience; and then it's often messy).

Comment: thanks "information". In that way i really can name the whole bunch of object programmatically. I also is the answer when there is "no answer". I guess is some work but i could manage a pre-made function to make it easy in the future. I will learn how to manage texts files and create them programmatically (i guess thats the word).

Comment: For sure.  I don't have time right now, but will try and update the answer in the next day or to give you some direction on how to do this.  It's not too hard to create simple source code files this way, but the indirection gets to be a pain as you get more and more complex with what you want to do.

Comment: @PabloLopez Let me know if this works for you.  If so, we may be able to edit your question a bit more so people aren't as thrown off.  At first glance and based on the comments, it seems like you are suggesting a self modifying source code, which is kind of like asking if there is a way you can write on a piece of paper and then have that same piece of paper rewrite itself based on what you wrote.  That would take some magic :)  But clearly it can still be done if you have one program write the other, and there may be better suggestions from others if they see it this way too.

Answer (score 0):

This might be the dumbest answer but if I understood what you are trying to do, this is dumb anyway.

If what you want is to declare objects of type Person, and that the name of the Object (here I mean the name of the variable) is set from a string, I don't think it is possible.

`listOfPersons[i]` is a string object, that might be equal to another string object somewhere else in your program (you can have two "Johns" strings in your array for example).

But when you declare a variable of type Person using:

```
Person person_name;
```

`person_name` is the unique id that refers to this variable of type `Person`, and this id can't be set programmaticaly because this is not a string, it is you who write it when you write your C++ code file. So if what you want is to have objects declared like that :

```
Person john;
Person patricia;
Person edward;
//...
```

You just CANNOT do it otherwise than manually. And particulary not in a *for* loop from an array of string because this is just non sense.

If what you want is access `Person` objects using a string, what you want to use is a `map`:

```
using <map>

class Person 
{
// bla bla bla
};

string listOfPersons [5000];
std::map<string, Person> persons;

// here i will fill in the whole array with names

for (int i=0;i<5000);i++){
    Person temp;  // declare a temp Person object. Here you might instead want to use a constructor that you defined.
    persons[listOfPersons[i]] = temp; // Add the Person object into the map

    // This will be like doing persons["Patricia"] = temp;    
}
```

Then when you want to access the objects, you can just call:

```
persons["name"];
```

And do what you want with it. You can also use iterator to do operations on the whole persons map.

Comment: all right, thanks for the teaching. there is an alternative way to do it. Sad you said: "I don't think it is possible". There is always a way. Thanks a lot again for your time.

Comment: Think about when you declare an int, you write "int i = 0" for example. There is absolutely no way to set the name of the variable (here "i") programmatically from the code, because this code is supposed to be compiled, and the code itself can't depend on what will happen at runtime.

Comment: @PabloLopez in this case the answer is indeed "there is no way". C++ doesn't have reflection (yet), let alone introspection which is what you need to create variables named at runtime.